# What does this notation mean: matrix norm with a two-number subscript

Tags: norms, notation, matrices

I recently came across this notation, without explanation, in a paper:

$||\mathbf{W}||_{2,1}$

From the context, I know that $\mathbf{W}$ is a matrix, which could be any size, and that $||\mathbf{W}||_{2,1}$ must be a scalar.  Can anyone tell me what this means, or just what it's called, so I can look it up?

Comment: Guess 1:  norm as a transformation from $l^1$ to $l^2$.  Guess 2:  norm as an operator on Sobolev space $W_{1,2}$.  Perhaps the rest of the paper suggests the area more specifically than this...

Comment: Perhaps it means the maximum value of the $L_1$-norm of $Wx$ divided by the $L_2$-norm of $x$ over all nonzero $x$.

Comment: Will Sawin, I see Wikipedia uses this notation with that meaning (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm, a bit past the halfway point in the "Induced norm" section). I don't know how I failed to find this before, but I guess this is probably it.

Comment: Similar questions about "mixed-norms" have been previously answered either on MO or M.SE; voting to close this one. It can mean many things; one common and easy to remember instance of $\|X\|_{p,q}$ is that it is the $p$-norm of the vector formed by computing $q$-norms of the columns of $X$.... 